# Substitution till the end of the line in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a huge text file with lots of lines like:

```
asdasdasdaasdasd_DATA_3424223423423423
gsgsdgsgs_DATA_6846343636
```

.....

I would like to do, for each line, to substitute from DATA_ .. to the end, with just empty space so I would get:

```
asdasdasdaasdasd_DATA_
gsgsdgsgs_DATA_
```

.....

I know that you can do something similar with:

```
sed -e "s/^DATA_*$/DATA_/g" filename.txt
```

but it does not work.

Do you know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular expressions, `*` means **the previous character, any number of times**. To match any character, use `.`

So what you really want is `.*` which means **any character, any number of times**, like this:

```
sed 's/DATA_.*/DATA_/' filename.txt
```

Also, I removed the `^` which means **start of line**, since you want to match "DATA_" even if it's not in the beginning of a line.

Comment: This actually won't work with the sample data - `DATA_` is not at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Jefromi: saw that just after posting - not enough coffee yet! :)

Comment: great, this works now ! just a las t question, how can one do the oppositve, i mean, instead of after DATA_ to the end, just remove everything before DATA_ ?

Comment: This still has the unnecessary `g` as I explain in my answer, and the `$` is not necessary since `.*` will always match until the end of line anyway.

Comment: @Werner: if you understand how `s/DATA_.*/DATA_/` works, you should be able to answer your next question too. Can't always come ask SO to write every regex for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems: you're unnecessarily matching beginning and end of line with `^` and `$`, and you're looking for `_*` (zero or more underscores) instead of `.*` (zero or more of any character. Here's what you want:

```
sed -e 's/_DATA_.*/_DATA_/'
```

The `g` on the end (global) won't do anything, because you're already going to remove everything from the first instance of "*DATA*" onward - there can't be another match.

P.S. The `-e` isn't strictly necessary if you only have one expression, but if you think you might tack more on, it's a convenient habit.

Answer (score 1):

using awk. Set field delimiter as "*DATA*", then get field 1 (`$1`). No need regular expression

```
$ awk -F"_DATA_" '{print $1"_DATA_"}' file
asdasdasdaasdasd_DATA_
gsgsdgsgs_DATA_
```